# Is index like key(timetime) usable when we query: SELECT * ....... ORDER BY timetime DESC

Tags: mysql, index, order-by

When we index a timestamp field like timetime. Can we use it for `ORDER BY timetime DESC` or is it just usable for `ORDER BY timetime ASC` OR `ORDER BY timetime`? Does mySQL use this index when doing vise verse ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. MySQL can use the index and use it for scanning/seeking in either direction. You can read in MySQL documentation: [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> To sort or group a table if the sorting or grouping is done on a leftmost prefix of a usable key (for example, `ORDER BY key_part1, key_part2`). If all key parts are followed by `DESC`, **the key is read in reverse order**. See Section 8.13.9, [“`ORDER BY` Optimization”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html), and Section 8.13.10, [“`GROUP BY` Optimization”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-optimization.html).